# How do I convert a string to bytes with unix line endings?

Tags: c#, .net, string, text, ascii

If I convert a string to bytes using:

```
byte[] ascii = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(myString);
```

Then the bytes I get back use Windows line endings. How can I convert it using Unix line endings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line endings are independent of the encoding. If you want to convert Windows line endings to Unix line endings, do that in the string itself:

```
myString = myString.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
```

Personally I avoid using ASCII wherever possible, by the way - are you absolutely sure it will never need any accented characters? If I get the choice, I usually use UTF-8:

```
myString = myString.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
```

If you're writing to a stream somewhere, any alternative is to use `StreamWriter`, or `File.CreateText` etc. Then you specify the encoding once but don't need to deal with the raw bytes yourself.

Comment: +1 for UTF8 over Ascii.  However, using Environment.NewLine over "\r\n" would be better

Comment: @Richard: Why? The question asked how to convert *Windows* line terminators to Unix ones... not "my system's current line terminators" to Unix ones. My answer is code which exactly matches the question. What if this is actually running on Mono, and is loading a file which was generated in Windows, for example?

Answer (score 2):

```
string myString = @"line 1
line 2";
byte[] ascii = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(myString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n"));
```